# jest, logging success or failure between each test while the tests are running

Tags: testing, logging, jasmine, specifications, jestjs

seems like something quite basic but it dosen't seem to be available in jest automatically.

when i run my jest tests, during the test run i get the logging info from the code itself while the tests are run.

and only after the tests are finished i receive a summary of the spec results(which tests passed and which didn't).

what i'm trying to achieve is to have extra lines in my console, that fill while the tests are running, that tell which test we have just finished, and what was the result.. this will make log debugging so much simpler..

thanks!